# How to set MYSQL column to certain value if a certain row exists?

Tags: mysql

I want to generate a new column in my table that is true if a row exists with certain conditions.

```
name | col1 | col2 | flag
--------------------------
a      1      2      0
a      2      3      0
b      1      2      0
b      4      3      0
```

Lets say I want to set the flag to 1 for every `name` identifier if a row exists with that `name` and where `col1=2` and `col2 = 3`. So this would result in:

```
name | col1 | col2 | flag
--------------------------
a      1      2      1
a      2      3      1
b      1      2      0
b      4      3      0
```

because for `a` a row with `col1=2` and `col2 = 3` exists, but for `b`, such a row doesn't exist.

In pseudocode I want something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD flag TINYINT(1)
IF ##row with condition col1=value1 and col2=value2 exists#
GROUP BY name
```

How can I generate this column?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` is for changing the table schema, not modifying the data in the table. `UPDATE` and `iNSERT` are for modifying and adding rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want just to get those values from db? or you want to add column? those are 2 different goals.

So if you need just to get those values you can:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65b4c2/1

```
SELECT t.*, t2.flag
FROM table_name t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT name, MAX(IF(col1=2 AND col2=3,1,0)) flag
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY name
  ) t2
ON t.name = t2.name
```

and if you really need to add new column then you go this way:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/226fb3/1

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN flag TINYINT;

UPDATE table_name t
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT name, MAX(IF(col1=2 AND col2=3,1,0)) flag
      FROM table_name
      GROUP BY name
      ) t2
ON t.name = t2.name
SET t.flag=t2.flag
```