# How to conditionally set value for mysql row group?

Tags: mysql

I want to set the value of a column in a row to 1 if the group, that the row belongs to, fulfills a condition from another column.

Here is an example. Given this *table1*,

```
name | col | flag
------------------
a      1     0
a      2     0
b      1     0
b      4     0
c      2     0
c      3     0
```

I want to set all flag column entries to 1 where the name-column group contains a row with col=2. So the table above would be afterwards

```
name | col | flag
------------------
a      1     1
a      2     1
b      1     0
b      4     0
c      2     1
c      3     1
```

I have the following code, but it doesn't seem to work (ie. all flag entries stay 0)

```
UPDATE table1 t
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT name, col=2 flag
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY name
      ) t2
ON t.name = t2.name
SET t.flag=t2.flag
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Isn't this similar to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057743/how-to-set-mysql-column-to-certain-value-if-a-certain-row-exists? The only difference is that you're just checking one column instead of two.

Comment: You should use the same solution, with `MAX()` in the subquery.